# Is it possible to retrieve an echo from a bash script, from a java project running on a different server?

Tags: java, bash, spring-boot, logging

I'm not sure I'm asking this correctly, but...

Given server A running a java(Spring Boot) program calls server B to execute a bash script. Is it possible to echo from server B to server A (or something similar) in real time?

These are independent ecosystems so, we are unable to have both on the same server. But we need to see the echo's occurring on server B to show in server A's logs for debugging purposes.

Comment: You can do an asynchronous call that will contain finished result of script. If realtime processing is needed than some examples of such feature might be Jenkins or Bamboo. Both using runners on many external nodes, realtime results are available during build.

Comment: Yes, you can run the script via SSH and read its output from Java as if it was a local process.